# How to convert bmp to jpg on GAE side?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a bmp image link, this image I would like to save in my datastore. So, I would prefer to convert that to jpg. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [ImageService](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html) which in fact can only return JPEG, PNG and WEBP but can read BMP.

Answer (score 0):

```
bmp_file = 'foo.bmp'
jpg_file = 'foo.jpg'
import google.appengine.api.images
with open(bmp_file, 'rb') as bmp_fd:
    image = google.appengine.api.images.Image(bmp_file.read())
with open(jpg_file, 'wb') as jpg_fd:
    jpg_fd.write(image.execute_transforms(output_encoding=google.appengine.api.images.JPEG))
```

Comment: Except you can't write to files on App Engine, and the uploaded image isn't on his local filesystem.